# JSONObject override JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, overriding

I try to put JSONObject values on a JSONArray on a "for" instruction and with the first value group it works correctly, but when I add the second value group I see that the first values are override too. I put the code and an examepl to explain it better.

```
JSONArray jsPoints = new JSONArray();
JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
{                               
    try 
    {
       js.put("id",points[i]._id);
       js.put("calification",points[i]._calification);
       js.put("comment",points[i]._comment);
       js.put("gps",points[i]._coords);
       js.put("X",points[i]._X);
       js.put("Y",points[i]._Y);
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) 
    {                               
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    jsPoints.put(js);
}
```

I have, for example, this value gruops:

On i = 0:

id: 1 - calification: 0 - comment: "hi" - gps: 0 - X: 220 - Y: 110

On i = 1;

id: 2 - calification: 2 - comment: "hello" - gps: 40.324 - X: 10 - Y: 52

When I put the first values (i = 0), I added on jsPoints correctly, but when I put the second values (i = 1) the first values are override by the second one, how can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONArray jsPoints = new JSONArray();

for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
{       
 JSONObject js = null;

try 
{
   js = new JSONObject();  
   js.put("id",points[i]._id);
   js.put("calification",points[i]._calification);
   js.put("comment",points[i]._comment);
   js.put("gps",points[i]._coords);
   js.put("X",points[i]._X);
   js.put("Y",points[i]._Y);
} 
catch (JSONException e) 
{                               
   e.printStackTrace();
}
  if(js!=null)
    jsPoints.put(js);
```

}

Comment: the accumulate method have one problem on my chase, the values that I recieve when I use that are like this: [{"id":["3;","3;"],"gps":[";",";"],"calification":["0;","1;"],"Y":[66,43],"comment":[";","ffff;"],"X":[17,31]},{"id":["3;","3;"],"gps":[";",";"],"calification":["0;","1;"],"Y":[66,43],"comment":[";","ffff;"],"X":[17,31]}]. I mean, that are duplicated and I don't want this, I want to have something like this: [{"id":["3;"],"gps":[";"],"calification":["0;"],"Y":[66],"comment":[";"],"X":[17]},{"id":["3;"],"gps":[";"],"calification":["1;"],"Y":[43],"comment":["ffff;"],"X":[31]}]

Comment: i edit my answers. please check this, you should to refresh your old json object only. no need of accumulate :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 try 
{
 JSONObject js = new JSONObject();

JSONArray jsPoints = new JSONArray();

for(int i = 0; i < jsPoints.length; i++)
 {                               

   js.put("id",points[i]._id);
   js.put("calification",points[i]._calification);
   js.put("comment",points[i]._comment);
   js.put("gps",points[i]._coords);
   js.put("X",points[i]._X);
   js.put("Y",points[i]._Y);
} 
catch (JSONException e) 
{                               
   e.printStackTrace();
}
jsPoints.put(js);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work, you just only change the lines of the JSONObject and JSONArray declaration, it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: what response you receive from url/api

Comment: what do you mean? The response of the logcat?

Comment: what value you put in JSONObject....... and In JSONArray what value you receive in array (array name)

Comment: I put the values I wrote in my question: 

On i = 0: id: 1 - calification: 0 - comment: "hi" - gps: 0 - X: 220 - Y: 110

On i = 1; id: 2 - calification: 2 - comment: "hello" - gps: 40.324 - X: 10 - Y: 52

And the values that I put in jsPoints arrays are "js" values, but the last values override the first with my code and with your code. Any idea?

Comment: where from did you get this data....i = 0: id: 1 - calification: 0 - comment: "hi" - gps: 0 - X: 220 - Y: 110 On i = 1; id: 2 - calification: 2 - comment: "hello" - gps: 40.324 - X: 10 - Y: 52